# RHEL8 repo does not have python-sphinx package

Tags: rhel, python, yum

Can't seem to find `python-sphinx` packages on freshly installed RHEL8. Previously on CentOS-7 there was an easy way to `yum install python-sphinx`. Should I be add another repo containing `sphinx` packages? I'm interested in `python3-sphinx` and `python3-sphinx_rtd_theme` (this are their names in CentOS-7)

Comment: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/python3-sphinx-1.7.6-2.el8.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: Sorry, RHEL... Then https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1772480 
`codready-builder repo `

Comment: Thank you, https://serverfault.com/questions/1034517/how-can-i-enable-powertools-repository-in-centos-rhel-8 explains how to add the repository.